# Demonstrate that $\frac{1}{e^e} - 1 + e - \frac{e^2}{2} + \frac{e^3}{6}\ge 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series, taylor-expansion

How do I prove the inequality?

$$\frac{1}{e^e} - 1 + e - \frac{e^2}{2} + \frac{e^3}{6} \geq 0$$

I can see that $e^e = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^k}{k!} = 1 + e + \frac{e^2}{2} + \frac{e^3}{6}+\dots \geq 0$ but Im unsure of the next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost on the right track. Look at the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Secondary hint:
If the sequence $(a_n)$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n\ge 0$.

Tertiary hint: $e<3$

Comment: yes, it is - thanks

Comment: I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, **Hint**:
 $$e^{-e} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-e)^k}{k!}= 1-e+\frac{e^2}{2}-\frac{e^3}{6}+\sum_{k = 4}^\infty \frac{(-e)^k}{k!}$$
Now you need to show
$$\sum_{k = 4}^\infty \frac{(-e)^k}{k!}\ge0$$